# Multi optional parameters for controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need pass 2 optional parameters to controller, in route I have:

```
Route::get('/products/{start?}/{end?}', 'productsController@index');
```

In `Products` controller I have:

```
public function index($start = NULL, $end = NULL) {
    // ....
}
```

This works fine if there is passed both of arguments,  but how to handle situation, were we need pass only `$end` parameter? because when passed only one parameter, it always goes to as `$start` parameter.

Comment: How are you passing the params to the route function ?

Comment: @danish-khan-I -    from URL, like: `.../products/a/b`

Comment: to you what would the URL look like if you were only trying to use the second route parameter? what would the URL look like with only using the first? is there any difference in how those URLS look?

Comment: @lagbox - May be something like: `products/end:value`, though this not much different from default `GET` parameters passing style

Comment: are there situations where you only will use `start` or is it always just `end` or both of them?

Comment: @lagbox - all of 3 cases (only start, only end, both of them) may happen

Comment: if you'd use `route('someroute',[$start,$end])` the result will be `example.com//b`. start will be empty.

Comment: @danish-khan-I - but this will very ugly if we have for example 10 parameters ))

Comment: yes it will @OTAR then  the named params is the best for empty urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should cover route  add param `products?start=&end=`

```
Route::get('/products', 'productsController@index');

public function index() {
    $start = request()->input('start');
    $end = request()->input('end');
     // ....
}
```

you easy handle it.

Comment: Thanks, this will work, just this means that laravel's route parameter passing style `/{param?}` is useless, when we may have more than 1 parameter ?

Comment: no, it means you can't just skip parameters which are segments in this case ... can't get to the second segment if there isn't a first segment .. if there is only 1 segment then there is no second segment

Comment: Your endpoint is /products and start/end are filters, for filter query strings should be used, so /products?start=&end= is the right thing to do

Answer (score 2):

*In your Route.php file*

```
Route::get('/products', 'productsController@create');
```

*In your controller file*

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $start = $request->start;
    $end = $request->end;
}
```

**or**

```
Route::get('/products/{start?}/{end?}', 'productsController@index');

public function index($start= null, $end= null)
    {
        $variable = DB::table('name table')->paginate(16);
        if($start!=null) {
            //some code
        }
        if($end!=null) {
            //some code
        }
        return somethingt;
    }
```